# Set email as foreign key in Odoo 10

Tags: foreign-keys, one-to-many, models, odoo, many-to-one

I have a model named `Joked` and I wish to store the email of the current user as foreign key. In my model I have defined my M2O relationship as shown:

`last_accessed_by = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Complainant id', default=lambda self: self.env.uid, required = True)`

However, it takes the id of the user and not the email.

Comment: You are explicitly telling it to store a `res.users` object and defaulting it to the user ID. Can you better explain what you are wanting and possibly why? It seems like a strange use case. Typically, you would store the user ID and display any related fields you need.

Comment: This is because I require sending email to the user. And using the automated action for emails, it just fetches the user's email from the database using `${object.last_accessed_by}` to send to that user. I am having difficulty in getting the user's email if i use the user id as foreign key. Do you have any idea how to get the user's email while i use the user id as foreign key @travisw?

Answer (score 0):

In the email template, you can continue using dot notation to access a sub-object’s attributes.

In your case, when you get `object.last_accessed_by`, you are getting a `res.users` object. You can continue accessing attributes until you get to what you need.

Additionally, all models in Odoo have a few “builtin” fields. One of those is `write_uid, which stores what user last modified the record.

I would suggest using it instead of your `last_accessed_by` field since the seem to be identical. You could end up with something like this:

```
object.write_uid.partner_id.email
```